# How can I configure my Linux host to NOT connect to a 2nd bridged interface that uses a different VLAN?

Tags: networking, network-interface, networkmanager, kvm, virt-manager

My computer is connected to a port on my switch that allows VLAN 10 (default) and VLAN 20.

My computer only has 1 ethernet card: `eno1`.

On my computer, I have created two bridged interface:

- `br0` where the slave is `eno1`
- `br1` where the slave is on VLAN `eno1.20`

My computer is getting an IP on both `br0` (VLAN 10) and `br1` (VLAN 20).

I want it to NOT get an IP on `br1` (VLAN 20). I will be running KVM/virt-manager VMs that will use `br1` (VLAN 20) but I don't want the host to get an IP on it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: you've tagged `networkmanager`, so I gather you are actually using networkmanager? my guess is, you'd configure the bridge without an ip address (including obtaining one automatically)